# Use the autocomplete event in the succes of my ajax

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to use an autocompletion in my application. I'm trying to use the jquery UI completion but nothing happens. I made an ajax to get all columns with a specific variable written by the user. The query is working, I have my array with all my columns back from the server. With this query reponse, I tried to do the jquery autocompletion in the success ajax but as I said nothing is happening.

Do you have an idea?

```
function autoCompleteRegate(){
$("#code_regate").keyup(function() {
    // AJAX de l'auto-complete
    var source = '/gestion/gestDepot/ajaxautocompleteregate';
    var codeRegate = $("#code_regate").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : source,
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
            'codeRegate' : codeRegate
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var availableTags = response;
            $("#code_regate").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        }
    });
});

public function ajaxautocompleteregateAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    $params = $this->_getAllParams();
    $codeRegate = $params['codeRegate'];

    $oDepotService = new Services_Depot();
    $response = $oDepotService->searchCodeRegate($codeRegate);

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

[Network query - form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8xab.png)

[Exemple of nothing happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP0XZ.png)

[The answer from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUNvv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to directly pass the `cd_regate` array instead of a multidimensional array. One workaround is you could process the json output on the backend side :

```
public function ajaxautocompleteregateAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    $params = $this->_getAllParams();
    $codeRegate = $params['codeRegate'];

    $oDepotService = new Services_Depot();
    $response = $oDepotService->searchCodeRegate($codeRegate);
    $json = [];
    foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
        array_push($json, $value->cd_regate); // the output will be "[774970, 774690, 774700,... ]"
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following for your JavaScript:

```
$("#code_regate").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : '/gestion/gestDepot/ajaxautocompleteregate',
      async : false,
      dataType : 'json',
      data : {
        'codeRegate' : request.term
      },
      success : function(data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This uses a function as a Source. From the API:

> **Function:** The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete, including JSONP. The callback gets two arguments:
>
> - A `request` object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters `"new yo"` in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal `"new yo"`.
> - A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the `response` callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.
>
> When filtering data locally, you can make use of the built-in `$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex` function. It'll take a single string argument and escape all regex characters, making the result safe to pass to `new RegExp()`.

When 1 or more letters are entered into the text field, this will be passed to the function under `request.term` and you can POST that to your script via AJAX. When you get the result `data`, it must be in an Array or an Object with the right format.